# Why does work particle system only once?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, particle-system

I am working on an explosion-like particle system with SpriteKit / Swift 2.2 targeting iOS 9.3 like described in [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GciqoWDH0cU).

My (simplified) code:

```
let emiExplode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ExplosionParticleSystem.sks")

private func initEmitters() {
    emiExplode?.particleBirthRate = 0.0
    emiExplode?.targetNode = scene
    emiExplode?.zPosition = 1
    scene.addChild(emiExplode!)
}

private func explode() {
    emiExplode?.position = self.position
    emiExplode?.particleBirthRate = 2000.0
    // remove explosion particle system shortly after
    let action = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5),
                                    SKAction.runBlock( { self.emiExplode?.particleBirthRate = 0 })])
     emiExplode?.runAction(action)
}
```

The first time I call explode() it works like a charm. But the second time, the particle effect is not visible...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution meanwhile:

```
self.emiExplode?.resetSimulation()
```

... did the trick.